# If $A$ is an abelian group and $F$ is a field then how to show that the Torsion product $A *F$ is zero?

Tags: field-theory, modules, tensor-products, abelian-groups

Let $A$ be an abelian group $F$ be a field , so $(F,+)$ is an abelian group ; then how to show that the Torsion product ( see ["Torsion product" of two abelian groups , at least one of which is torsion free , is trivial (zero)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2265130/torsion-product-of-two-abelian-groups-at-least-one-of-which-is-torsion-free)    for definition )  $A *B=0$ ?

Comment: Not true if $A$ and $F$ have the same prime order.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown : how do you claim that ?

Comment: The torsion product of two cyclic groups of order $p$ also has order $p$.